# python prefix string with backslash

Tags: python, string

I am looking for a way to prefix strings in python with a single backslash, e.g. "]" -> "]". Since "\" is not a valid string in python, the simple

```
mystring = '\' + mystring
```

won't work. What I am currently doing is something like this:

```
mystring = r'\@@@' + mystring
mystring.replace('@@@','')
```

While this works most of the time, it is not elegant and also can cause problems for strings containing "@@@" or whatever the "filler" is set to. Is there a bette way of doing this?

Comment: Just use `mystring = '\\' + mystring` -- you must "escape" literal backslash characters in a string with another backslash.

Comment: See the line starting with "The backslash (\) character is used to escape characters..." in the [String Literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python strings have a feature called escape characters. These allow you to do special things inside as string, such as showing a quote (" or ') without closing the string you're typing

[See this table](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

So when you typed

```
mystring = '\' + mystring
```

the \' is an escaped apostrophe, meaning that your string now has an apostrophe in it, meaning it isn't actually closed, which you can see because the rest of that line is coloured.

To type a backslash, you must escape one, which is done like this:

```
>>> aBackSlash = '\\'
>>> print(aBackSlash)
\
```

Comment: To all other answerers: thank you for your support - from all the valid answers it was hard to choose, since most of them are rather similar. sorry for not choosing yours :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to *escape* the backslash with a second one, to make it a literal backslash:

```
mystring = "\\" + mystring
```

Otherwise it thinks you're trying to escape the `"`, which in turn means you have no quote to terminate the string

Ordinarily, you can use raw string notation (`r'string'`), but that won't work when the backslash is the last character

---

The difference between `print a` and just `a`:

```
>>> a = 'hello'
>>> a = '\\' + a
>>> a
'\\hello'
>>> print a
\hello
```

Comment: It does work. But when you just type `a` it prints the escaped string (the `repr`). `print a` displays it correctly

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the backslash as follows:

```
mystring = "\\" + mystring
```

This is because if you do `'\'` it will end up escaping the second quotation. Therefore to treat the backslash literally, you must escape it.

#### Examples

```
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> s = '\\' + s
>>> print
\hello
```

#### Your case

```
>>> mystring = 'it actually does work'
>>> mystring = '\\' + mystring
>>> print mystring
\it actually does work
```

Comment: @Isaac, Actually there is a difference between printing a string and display its values. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

As a different way of approaching the problem, have you considered string formatting?

```
r'\%s' % mystring
```

or:

```
r'\{}'.format(mystring)
```